# Need to fill color in circle while scroll down and up?

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to fill the color for a circle when we move the scroll up and down in browser. Moving page up and down.

Please Help.

Comment: Can explain more about your question!

Comment: Well we would like to see your tries? FYI you can use jquery and jquery ui for color animation.

Comment: I need colors to help fill the circle scroller up and down while moving! Pleaze HAAALP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery and jquery ui you can use the mousewheel event.

`$('#...').bind('mousewheel', function(e) { });`

here is an example, that should help you get started:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFmQu/)

some more info:

[The onmousewheel event of JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml)